# Point $A$ is the terminal point of $\phi$ and point $B$ is the terminal point of $\theta$. Point

Tags: algebra-precalculus

Point $A$ is the terminal point of $\phi$ and point $B$ is the terminal point of $\theta$. Point $A$ is in the first quadrant and point $B$ is in the second quadrant, while $\tan \phi = 1$ and $\tan \theta = -7$. Find the slope of $\overline{AB}$.

I found out that A would be ($\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$, $\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2}$)

What would point B be? And what would be the slope?

Comment: Of course. Trig finctions have to be in the unit circle.

Answer (score 2):

Using $1+\tan^2\theta =\frac{1}{\cos^2\theta}$, we get $\cos^2\theta = \frac{1}{1+49} = 1/50$.

As theta is in the second quadrant, its cosines is negative and sinus positive, and we have the coordinates of the point $B$ : $(-1/\sqrt{50}, 7/\sqrt{50})$.

Now the calculus of the distance $AB$ is easy.

Answer (score 1):

Point A:$(\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2},\frac{\sqrt{2}}{2})$
Point B:$(-\frac{\sqrt{2}}{10}, \frac{7\sqrt{2}}{10})$

Finding the slope,

$\frac{\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{10}}{\frac{-6\sqrt{2}}{10}}=-\frac{2\sqrt{2}}{6\sqrt{2}}=\boxed{-\frac{1}{3}}$

Comment: Remember that the slope is $$m = \frac{y_1 - y_2}{x_1 - x_2}$$  You calculated its reciprocal.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig no he didn't...

Comment: @MichaelChirico  You are correct.  I looked at the problem too early in the morning to notice that the denominators were different.

Comment: @N.F.Taussig to be honest I made the same mistake a few times even though I knew the end answer was right ><

Answer (score 1):

The other solutions are more trig-friendly, but alternatively, we could use a two-equations-two-variables approach to find the coordinates $(x,y)$ of $B$.

We know $\tan\theta=\frac{y}{x}=-7$; that $(x,y)$ is on the unit circle gives us a second constraint, namely that $x^2+y^2=1$.

Combining, we see (given $B$ is in quadrant II) $y=-7x\implies x^2=\frac{1}{50}\implies B=(-\frac{1}{\sqrt{50}},\frac{7}{\sqrt{50}})$

Then the slope is $\frac{\frac{7}{5}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}{-\frac{1}{5}\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}-\frac{1}{\sqrt{2}}}=\frac{\frac{7}{5}-1}{-\frac{1}{5}-1}=-\frac{1}{3}$.

Answer (score 0):

In general, suppose we've got $A$ and $B$ points on the unit circle corresponding to angles $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$, resp. and we're told $\tan\theta_1$ and $\tan\theta_2$.

The slope $m$ between $A=(\cos\theta_1,\sin\theta_1)$ and $B=(\cos\theta_2,\sin\theta_2)$ is $m=\frac{\sin\theta_1-\sin\theta_2}{\cos\theta_1-\cos\theta_2}=\frac{\frac{\tan\theta_1}{\cos\theta_2}-\frac{\tan\theta_2}{\cos\theta_1}}{\frac{1}{\cos\theta_2}-\frac{1}{\cos\theta_1}}=\frac{\tan\theta_1\sec\theta_2-\tan\theta_2\sec\theta_1}{\sec\theta_2-\sec\theta_1}$.

Now things are gonna get a bit messy, so let's introduce some notation.

Set $t_k=\tan\theta_k$; then $\sec^2\theta_k=1+t_k^2$, so $\sec\theta_k=\iota_k\sqrt{1+t_k^2}$, where $\iota_k=\pm1$ depending on which quadrant the angle's in.

Thus

$m=\frac{\iota_2t_1\sqrt{1+t_2^2}-\iota_1t_2\sqrt{1+t_1^2}}{\iota_2\sqrt{1+t_2^2}-\iota_1\sqrt{1+t_1^2}}=\frac{t_1t_2-1-\iota_1\iota_2\sqrt{(1+t_1^2)(1+t_2)^2}}{t_1+t_2}$ after some radical conjugation and simplifying.

Still a bit ugly, but we're going to express things in terms of the sum and difference of the tangents, i.e. set $\Sigma=t_1+t_2$ and $\Pi=t_1t_2$. Also define $\iota:=\iota_1\iota_2$

Then

$m=\frac{\Pi-1-\iota\sqrt{1+\Sigma^2+\Pi(\Pi-2)}}{\Sigma}$.

Using this handy chart to figure out the sign of $\iota$ given the quadrants of $\theta_1$ and $\theta_2$:

[image: iota_mapping]

(or perhaps it's easier to just check if $\theta_1,\theta_2$ are on the same or different sides of the $y$ axis)

We can quickly calculate for the question at hand that $\Sigma=-6,\Pi=-7$

So $m=\frac{-8+\sqrt{1+36+63}}{-6}=-\frac{1}{3}$.